# How to deploy nginx with ftp?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, ftp

Recently I start to stady Kubernetes. Now I know how to deploy nginx in pod with default options, and I know how  deply nginx with custom nginx.conf  with configmap. Now I have a question if I want to use nginx with ftp. Ftp need to have access in directory where nginx.conf. It is possible ?
Maybe someone know simple example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your ftp container as a sidecar for the `nginx` main container and share the volume between the containers:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: <your nginx image>
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      - name: ftp
        image: <your ftp image>
        ports:
        - name: ftp
          containerPort: 21
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
```

and the service expose both ports

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ftp
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: ftp
    port: 21
    targetPort: 21
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. But how deploy service ?

Comment: the service expose two ports, the ftp port and nginx port

Comment: Sory but how to deploy on that configuration configMap ? And what about authentification ? Using env ?